# Fetch document by _id in express and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express

I am trying to create a todo list, where i am using mlab as my db provider.

```
tasks = db.connect().collection('tasks');
tasks.find().toArray(function (err, result) {
            console.log("result", result) // giving me result
            if(err) throw err;
             res.render('tasks/index', {title:"Tasks",tasks:result});
         })
```

Attached is one single shot of all routes output in console.[image]

In the image (1) is the output of find().toArray()

(2) is get update and i am getting the id of task in the url route params.

(3) is after i run this findOne statment.

**update function -> get task based on id**

```
tasks.findOne({"_id":"59c91fbb4b262004f059f67f"}, function(err, task){
        console.log(err)
        console.log(task)
        res.render('tasks/update', {title:"Update"});
    });
```

I am getting null as value.(Note: I am hard coding the value for confirmation).

Let me know why i am getting null as the id matches (which you can refer from 1).

**Task-2**

Also, if i want to update, how shuld i send the altered values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first question, when matching on _id with Mongo you need to define your search criteria as an ObjectId :

```
tasks.findOne({"_id":ObjectId("59c91fbb4b262004f059f67f")}, function(err, task){
        console.log(err)
        console.log(task)
        res.render('tasks/update', {title:"Update"});
    });
```

Regarding the update, are you having some kind of trouble in particular ? The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) has plenty of information regarding the structure of the query you're supposed to send :)

Comment: In general correct. But one can assign any unique value as document._id Of course most of the time this field is populated with ObjectIds like Nicolas explained. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-id-field

Comment: I tried this it got an error. Excuse me. I will update the screenshot tomorrow.

Comment: i was missing this line var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID; and so it was giving me error. Thanks for the efforts.